# Recover WSL files using Linux Live USB?

Tags: usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-recovery

**The background**

- My Windows 10 laptop, with a bad battery, lost power during boot, and now cannot successfully boot windows (it tries to fix this with the Automatic Repair utility during startup, but fails every time).
- I want to boot the laptop into a Ubuntu live environment from a USB stick, and copy some files over from WSL distro to my USB stick.

**The problem**

- While I can access my Windows drive and all of my normal Windows files from my Ubuntu live USB, I can't seem to find any of my WSL files.

**The Question**

- It seems like I should be able run a command like `find . -type d -name "my-directory-in-wsl"` and figure out where WSL files live on my drive. I have tried this with no success. Should this work, or do WSL files live outside of the normal filesystem? Is there any hope for recovering these files?

Comment: WSL Files tend to be well hidden.  Try this:  Where are WSL files stored? WSL files are exposed through a network share \\wsl$\[distro name], for example my home directory is at \\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\pawelb. C:\Users\pawelb\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.   .......   https://solidstudio.io/blog/windows-subsystem-for-linux-explained

Comment: If you are using WSL2 then your files aren't directly on NTFS filesystem but inside the virtual drive VHD file placed in `%PROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\<distro package>\LocalState\ext4.vhdx`.

Comment: Was erroneously closed as a duplicate, which it wasn't because in this case the user is asking how to recover files from within a Ubuntu Live USB boot, not a Windows system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WSL2 (assumed, since you should find the WSL1 files on the drive with that search), then the entire filesystem for your WSL distribution is in a virtual SDD.  As @blami mentioned in the comments, you'll find that in:

```
%PROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\<distro package>\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
```

For Ubuntu (the default), the package name will start with *"Canonical"*.  So something like:

```
OldDriveLetter:\Users\<your_old_username>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
```

You can also search in `OldDriveLetter:\Users\<your_old_username>\AppData\Local\Packages` for any `ext4.vhdx` files.

Copy the `ext4.vhdx` file off to your USB drive.

As for recovering, the safest/best way would be to use another Windows system with the latest WSL installed and:

1. Copy the `ext4.vhdx` back to a location on the Windows system (preferred over trying to access it from the USB drive).  For the sake of the example below, we'll assume it's placed in `C:\WSL\instances\Recovered`.
2. Import the distribution into that WSL instance:

   ```
   wsl --import-in-place RecoveredWSL 
   C:\WSL\instances\Recovered\ext4.vhdx
   ```

   Note that this `wsl` command requires the WSL version that is
   installed from the Microsoft Store (or via `wsl --install` on the latest Windows releases).

   Feel free to use a different name, of course.  Once imported, you can access the distribution via:

   ```
   wsl ~ -d RecoveredWSL
   ```

   You can also set it as default, so it can simply be launched via `wsl`:

   ```
   wsl --set-default RecoveredWSL
   ```

If you really need to access the files from a "real" Ubuntu instance, it *may* be a bit more complicated, as you'll need to mount that `vhdx` file into Ubuntu.  I haven't done that myself, but some see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/763548/1165986) on Ask Ubuntu for a possibility.

**Important:** If accessing the `ext4.vhdx` using this method, please make sure you are working from a secondary copy, as other questions on Ask Ubuntu indicate the *possibility* of corruption using these tools.